# Unable to fillna a column in dataframe with values from a series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fillna in a specific column of the dataframe with the mean of not-null values of the same type (based on the value from another column in the dataframe).
Here is the code to reproduce my issue:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
#Create the DateFrame with a column of floats
#And a column of labels (str)
np.random.seed(seed=6)
df['col0']=np.random.randn(100)    
lett=['a','b','c','d']
df['col1']=np.random.choice(lett,100)

#Set some of the floats to NaN for the test.
toz = np.random.randint(0,100,25)
df.loc[toz,'col0']=np.NaN
df[df['col0'].isnull()==False].count()

#Create a DF with mean for each label.
w_series = df.loc[(~df['col0'].isnull())].groupby('col1').mean()



        col0
col1    
a   0.057199
b   0.363899
c   -0.068074
d   0.251979

#This dataframe has our label (a,b,c,d) as the index. Doesn't seem
#to work when I try to df.fillna(w_series). So I try to reindex such
#that the labels (a,b,c,d) become a column again.
#
#For some reason I cannot just do a set_index and expect the
#old index to become column. So I append the new index and 
#then reset it.
w_series['col2'] = list(range(w_series.size))
w_frame = w_series.set_index('col2',append=True)
w_frame.reset_index('col1',inplace=True)

#I try fillna() with the new dataframe.
df.fillna(w_frame)
```

Still no luck:

```
        col0    col1
0   0.057199    b
1   0.729004    a
2   0.217821    d
3   0.251979    c
4   -2.486781   a
5   0.913252    b
6   NaN         a
7   NaN         b
```

What am I doing wrong?

How do I fillna the dataframe with the averages of specific rows that match the missing information?

Does the size of the dataframe being filled (df) and the filler dataframe (w_frame) have to match?

Thank you

Comment: Missing the `inplace` parameter:  `df.fillna(w_series, inplace=True)`

Comment: @A.Kot, I left the inplace=True just to get the printout to post. It did not make a difference if the fillna() had inplace or not.

Answer (score 0):

`fillna` is base on index, so , you need same index for your target dataframe and process dataframe

```
df.set_index('col1')['col0'].fillna(w_frame.set_index('col1').col0).reset_index()

# I only show the first 11 row
Out[74]: 
   col1      col0
0     b  0.363899
1     a  0.729004
2     d  0.217821
3     c -0.068074
4     a -2.486781
5     b  0.913252
6     a  0.057199
7     b  0.363899
8     c -0.068074
9     b -0.429894
10    a  2.631281
```

My way to `fillna`

```
df['col1']=df.groupby("col1")['col0'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me.
`
df.set_index('col1')['col0'].fillna(w_frame.set_index('col1').col0).reset_index()


col1 col0
0 b 0.057199
1 a 0.729004
2 d 0.217821
3 c 0.251979
4 a -2.486781
5 b 0.913252
6 NaN NaN
7 NaN NaN
8 NaN NaN
9 b -0.429894
`

I tried to understand what's going on but I think I will have to look at it with a fresh head.

And with the transform method, I get a value error:
`ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 79 elements, new values have 100 elements`
-SM
PS: I can't seem to get the format right in the comment. My apologies..

Comment: @SachinMyneni I am using you code create your df, and work fine in my end

Comment: The "My way to fillna" method is much slower on large dataframes. Would be nice to store the means and update the whole dataframe at once using a faster method.